# What is the magnitude of the vector given below conditions?

Tags: vectors, physics

Let vector B = 3m at 60 degree. Let vector C have the same magnitude as vector A. Vector C has a direction angle greater than of vector A by 25 degree. Dot product of A and B is 30. Dot product of B and C is 35. What is the magnitude and angle of vector A.

I know how to get the x and y components of vector B. I also know how the dot product is working but I'm stuck in forming equation so that I could get all their components. Any hint on how to attack this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that vectors A and C have magnitude A, and the angle of vector A is $\alpha$. Then, the angle of vector C is going to be $\alpha+25$.
Here are all components:
$$
A_x=A\cos(\alpha)\\
A_y=A\sin(\alpha)\\
B_x=3\cos(60)\\
B_y=3\sin(60)\\
C_x=A\cos(\alpha+25)\\
C_y=A\sin(\alpha+25)
$$
The dot product between A and B can be written as
$$
A\cdot B=A_xB_x+A_yB_y=3A(\cos(\alpha)\cos(60)+\sin(\alpha)\sin(60))=30
$$
or
$$A\cos(\alpha-60)=10$$
Similarly, for B and C:
$$
B\cdot C=B_xC_x+B_yC_y=3A(\cos(60)\cos(\alpha+25)+\sin(60)\sin(\alpha+25))=35
$$
or
$$3A\cos(35-\alpha)=35$$
From these equations, take the ratio, and you will get an equation in only $\alpha$, that you might need to solve numerically. Then just replace it into one of them, and you get A